# Podcast artwork shows in Apple Podcasts and iTunes but not on iPhone

Tags: iphone, itunes, ipod, podcasts

I submitted my first podcast to Apple Podcasts. The RSS feed has this tag for the icon:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><rss xmlns:dc="http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/" xmlns:content="http://purl.org/rss/1.0/modules/content/" xmlns:atom="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom" version="2.0" xmlns:itunes="http://www.itunes.com/dtds/podcast-1.0.dtd">
    <channel>
        <title><![CDATA[Ginja]]></title>
        <description><![CDATA[Um curso virtual que desenvolve a inteligência emocional nas crianças]]></description>
        <link>https://emocoes.org</link>
        <image>
            <url>http://emocoes.org/images/logo_podcast.png</url>
        ...
```

The artwork works, since I can see it on Apple Podcasts:

[image: Podcast on Apple Podcasts]

and on iTunes:

[image: Podcast on iTunes]

But syncing it on my iPhone 4S, I do not see the artwork when the podcast is playing:

[image: Podcast on iPhone when playing]

nor when browsing the library:

[image: Podcast on iPhone when browsing]

The iOS version is 9.3.6.

How can I change the podcast feed or artwork to show on all iPhones?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One solution is to embed the artwork into each audio file. Command-line solutions include `lame` and `ffmpeg`, for example:

```
lame --ti /path/to/file.jpg audio.mp3
ffmpeg -i input.mp3 -i cover.jpg -map_metadata 0 -map 0 -map 1 output.mp3
```

See more at: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/84915/add-album-art-cover-to-mp3-ogg-file-from-command-line-in-batch-mode

You can also download dedicated software for this purpose, though I did not try it.

Either way, if you handle the low-level of podcast distribution, remember to update the `length` attribute to reflect the now larger file, or else the duration may be computed from the file size and display the wrong number.